# Set online status in database to offline when exit the site ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I have a site and i want to set the user status in my database to 0 (Offline) when the user want to exit the site , the problem is i tried Page_Unload method but doesn't work.Thanks in advance!

```
protected void Page_Unload(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  try 
  {
    var conexiune = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    var SetareOnline = new SqlCommand("Update [dbo].[Table] Set Online=0 Where(UserName=@UserName)", conexiune);
    SetareOnline.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", Session["Login"].ToString());
    conexiune.Open();
    SetareOnline.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conexiune.Close();
  }
  catch {}
  finally {}
}
```

Comment: set breakpoints and set debugger & check whether `Page_Unload` is executing or not

Comment: Also remove the empty catch.

Comment: Ok, i checked and Page_Unload method is executed

Comment: I noticed my Page_Unload method is executed in same time with Page_Load method. In Page_Load method i change online status to 1 and after my Page_Unload method is executed and set online status to 0 so my problem is partial solved ,but why the Page_Unload method is executed when page load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess there is a confusion in how http protocol works. `Page_Unload` is getting called when server finishes fetching your page to client - that doesn't mean the client actively exits your site. As http is stateless you can't tell when user exits your site (he can look at your single page for 24 hours and server will not notice unless user will actively fetch another page from your domain). Also client don't send notification to server when he fetches page from different domain.

Given the cold facts, we usually compromise for tracking "inactive users":

- For every single request you mark user as active and include a timestamp
- User is considered inactive when his last activity is older than some time period (lets say 15 minutes)

If you need to track inactivity in seconds/tens of seconds you need to build a dead man switch

- On every single page you'll have javascript "pinger"
- This pinger will make AJAX request to your webservice - lets say every 30 seconds
- This webservice can have empty implementation, important thing is it has to update timestamp "LastActivity" for given user
- If user last activity is older than double the period of pinger - lets say one minute, user is considered inactive.

Other workaround may be using websockets.

Comment: Exactly , this is my problem.Thank you very much for help ,i will try another way to check when user exit the site.